# How to recompile php modules on wamp

Tags: php, module, compilation, pthreads, wamp

I receive some PHP errors that state a module cannot be initislised (in this case pthreads) because the module is compiled with a module API (20131226) whcih is different to PHP which is compiled with module API (20121212) and the options need to match.

On Linux I can go use phpize, ./configure and make to recompile a module.

How do I do that on windows where I am using wamp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WAMPServer does not come with a pthread dll by default, so you have just downloaded the wrong version.

Download one that is compiled with VC11 and not VC12.

[Try downloading from here](http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/pthreads/2.0.9/)